# Erro ao publicar na Apple

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ios, apache-cordova

Olá, estou tentando enviar meu primeiro aplicativo para apple, mas está dando um pouco de dor de cabeça..
Já procurei por todo o meu codigo, fiz uma limpeza total mas não encontro nada sobre câmera, e nem uso, porém estou recebendo esse erro ao enviar o app para revisão:

[image: erro]

Alguém já passou por isso?  Por favor, pode me ajudar? Já tentei algumas soluções que encontrei na internet,  mas não consegui..  ficarei feliz caso alguém tenha uma resposta pra isso. Pensei que talvez esse erro possa ser do plugin do facebook, mas não faz sentido pois ele não usa câmera, apenas pega a imagem e o nome do perfil.

Comment: Na `info.plist` do seu aplicativo você tem que colocar um texto informando que o app utiliza `Camera [NSCameraUsageDescription]` e a `Biblioteca de fotos [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription]`.

Comment: Hey @IcaroMartins, obrigado por responder, mas onde eu pego esse arquivo info.plist?  dentro do projeto não encontrei, apenas o config.xml

Comment: Faz muito tempo que eu não uso o cordova, acho que não deve ter mudado tanto assim, da uma olhada nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/a/47897726/2456894 nessa resposta mostra como colocar no config.xml, e em uma resposta acima mostra o info.plist

Comment: Você pode incluir pelo `config.xml`: `<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription"> <string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos and to scan barcodes.</string> </edit-config>` e `<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription"> <string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string> </edit-config>`.

Comment: Usei sua solução @Renata  como sempre correta. Muito obrigado a todos!!!  =D

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque a apple exige que você informe que seu aplicativo utiliza essas features no `info.plist`

Basicamente tem que colocar um texto para:

> [NSCameraUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW24) // Informação de acesso a Camera
>   [NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW17) // Informação de acesso a Biblioteca de fotos

### Para o cordova altere `config.xml`

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>You can upload your profile picture using your Photo Library</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
        <string>You can upload your profile picture using your camera</string>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

### Se você compila no `xcode` pode alterar direto no `info.plist`

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

Fontes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47897726/2456894 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/43138949/2456894